# Queryset has no attribute creator

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm me one more time.
I've an error when uploading a photo.
I've this model:

```
class UserPhoto(models.Model): 
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user/photos/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    photo_book = models.ForeignKey(UserPhotoBook, related_name='user_photo_book')
    creator = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and this is the view

```
@login_required(login_url='/quaba/login/')
    def photo_view(request, photo_id):
        user = UserProfile.objects.get_profile_user(request.user.email)
        photobook = UserPhotoBook.objects.get(user=user)
        photo = UserPhoto.objects.get_photo(photobook, photo_id)
        all_comments = UserPhotoComment.objects.filter(photo=photo)
        if photo.creator.email != user.email:
            pcr = False
        else:
            pcr = True
        return render_to_response('social_network/photos/photo_view.html',
                                 {'photo': photo, 'pcr': pcr, 'comm':    all_comments},
                                 context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The error is: ''QuerySet' object has no attribute 'creator''

I don't know why it's failing, because the 'creator' field IS in my model, I deleted the database file, resynchronized the database and is still throwing this error. Anyone can help me?

Comment: You should read the error message. It is telling you that you have a queryset, not a Photo instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `get_photo` from `UserPhoto`s manager is not returning an object, it is returning a `QuerySet` instead. Probably you are performing a `filter` and getting more that one result.